# How to highlight text moved from one object to another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

Hi I've got a quick question - how to highlight item when I moved him with unshift/push from list of selects to another list?

For example change for color blue for 1 second.

Comment: Use the [`enter` animation hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate#enter) with the `ng-repeat` directive. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`enter` animation hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate#enter) with the `ng-repeat` directive. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations).

### CSS

```
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
  color: blue;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

### HTML

```
  <ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ozKS93LZtLPsfgN19WNa?p=preview)

Comment: Can someone help me with one thing? This is great, I can style it in every way but it's one problem - when i reload page, all lists are highlighted for 2 seconds. Can I turn off it somehow?

Comment: Use the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to add/remove the CSS class, i.e. add/remove the `animate-repeat` class on the `<li>` element. See this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZAijt5h6LcKp4tuTib6z?p=preview).